# How do I print the text from function in email message?

Tags: python

Fairly new to python and currently exploring ways automate emails from functions. 
Everytime I send this message the text just says 'None' in my inbox.

```
def attendance_1(*students):

    #Would like this message to appear in body of text

    print(f"Hello, could you please send out an attendance text to the following student(s) 
    please:\n")
    for student in students:
        print(f"- {student}")
    print("\nThank you very much")

    #Info of students 
        example_1 = "example_1@gmail.com"
        example_2 ="example_2@gmail.com"


    #Send Message
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

    subject = 'Attendance warning 1'
    body = (attendance_1(example_1, example_2))

    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail(SENDER, RECEIVER, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def attendance_1(students):

    s = f"Hello, could you please send out an attendance text to the following student(s) please:\n"
    for student in students:
        s += f"- {student}"
    s += "\nThank you very much"

    return s

#Info of students 
students = ["example_1@gmail.com", "example_2@gmail.com"]

#Send Message
smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

subject = 'Attendance warning 1'
body = attendance_1(students)

msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

smtp.sendmail(SENDER, RECEIVER, msg)
```

I didn't test this code so there could be some errors.

Comment: So what's changed?